# How can I make the order of components correctly in C# (Window Form application)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a program using C# and I have lots of textbox and buttons. 
The thing is when I type something into textbox and type 'tap' button, it goes to weird area.
I mean, after I finish typing in the first textbox, I want to move to the second textbox using 'tap' button but it goes to third textbox (because I made third one before second one)
Is there any way to fix this easily? or should I make them from scratch?

Thanks

Comment: By "'tap' button," do you mean the tab key on the keyboard?

Comment: Yes, sorry for unclear question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the designer you should see a "TabIndex" property, use this as a sequence to specifiy the tab order: when you press 'Tab' the focus pass to the item having the index immediately grether than the current.

Answer (score 1):

Each control has a [`TabIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx) property.

Start with the first control in the tab order being 1 and increment it in the next control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the `TabIndex` property for this purpose

```
Assign 0 to first Textbox
Assign 1 to 2nd Textbox
Assign 2 to 3rd Textbox
Assign 3 to 4th Textbox
```

and so on

When you press the Tab button focus goes to control with 0 tab index and then 1 and so on

Answer (score 0):

You will want to set the tab order of your controls. See [How to: Set the Tab Order on Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for details on how to do that.